How to solve Server Error 5xx on my website?
Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site.
Top critical issues*
Server error (5xx)
*Critical issues prevent your page or feature from appearing in Search results.
We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.
Please tell me the solution of this Problem. I talk with hostinger support but they refer to your webiste.
